# set programmatically UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview

I have a little problem, why does this work:

```
self.view = mySecondView; (the view was changed)
```

while this:

```
self.myView = mySecondView; (the view was not changed)
```

doesn't? I have created an outlet

```
IBOutlet UIVIew* myView;
```

connected in IB. In my `.m` I've created a new view (mySecondView) programmatically, than with an action I try to set myView with this new view, the resolute is not work.
where is the error?

Answer (score 2):

If `myView` isn't declared as a property you can't use dot notation to access it. Try adding this to your .h file:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *myView;
```

and this to your .m file:

```
@synthesize myView;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view = mySecondView; (the view was changed)
```

This probably works because self is a UIViewController which has a view property (allowing you to use the dot notation) out of the box. Create a myView property:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIView *myView;
```